# How to install Elementary's Pantheon Mail client on Ubuntu (15.10)

Tags: software-installation, ppa, pantheon

I would like to tryout Pantheon Mail (a [Geary fork by Elementary OS)](http://blog.elementary.io/post/139731273161/re-geary) on Ubuntu (15.10). I found their [code hosting](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-mail) but I can't find how to install that. There's also [a Q&A about building from source on Elementary](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/apt-get-build-dep-command-fails-for-pantheon-mail-fails), but those steps don't work for me (apt-get can't find the `pantheon-mail` package).

I've tried adding `ppa:elementary-os/stable` and `ppa:elementary-os/daily` but this doesn't help. The stable one gives a 404 when doing an `apt-get update`, and the daily one works but still `pantheon-mail` package can not be found.

Googling for [ppa pantheon mail], I only find explanations about installing the whole Elementary/Pantheon desktop, which is *not* what I'm after.

Is there a way to install Elementary's Pantheon Mail on Ubuntu? Is there a PPA? Do I need to build from source and then how to?

Comment: I think this is a valid question. I'd also like to install this on 16.04. I can't find any link to the source to build it (assuming I can without panthenon desktop installed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there were no upvoted answer and community bumped this so that it can be answered. But 15.10 being EOL now, we can't verify the answer I think

Comment: @Anwar the question is not really specific to 15.10. I could remove that reference from the title if it helps? Because the problem is still unresolved.

Comment: @Lode that's nice. Are you still having it with non-EOL ubuntu? If yes, then please remove the version tag. I'll vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Voting to reopen since 15.10 wasn't EOL when the question was asked, and it doesn't seem to be version-specific.

Comment: Since the question is now opened can you verify the answer for its correctness? If so, then try upvoting or accepting that answer. If it doesn't solve, comment on the answer. Please don't leave the question unanswered. Thanks

Comment: Right now I was able to successfully install the package `pantheon-mail` after adding `ppa:elementary-os/stable` to the list on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @kcpr Please write your comment as an answer. It works, as I verified. OP should decide which answer to accept.

Answer (score 4):

Right now I was able to successfully install the package `pantheon-mail` after adding `ppa:elementary-os/stable` to the list on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `.deb` file at launchpad, [for example](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily/+build/9697962) then manually install.
It works fine for me, some icons are missing, look better than Geary (Ubuntu 16.04). Of course, you need to install any required dependencies.

You can do so by this command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```